# Printf Symbol Resolution

Tags: c, elf, ptrace, objdump, readelf

I'm writing a little program which trace all the syscall and calls of a binary file (elf) using ptrace (singlestep, getregs, pick_text, opcodes comparison, etc).

So far I've succeed to trace syscalls and simple calls like user defined functions.

But I failed to get the name of the printf symbol from the address I pick thanks to ptrace.

**My question is:** For dynamic linked function as printf, strlen, etc, how can I retrieve in the elf file the name of the symbol from the address ?

With simple calls it's kind of easy, I run through the .strtab section and when an address match I return the corresponding str.

But for printf, the symbol is known in the .strtab but has the address "0".

objdump -d somehow succeed to link a call to printf with its address.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is dynamic linking involved?

Comment: In the glibc, the symbol for `printf` is actually called `__printf_chk` because of the fortification patch. Run `nm` on an object file that calls `printf` and you'll see. Generally, have a look at the libelf as for how to parse elf files. I recommend you to not parse them manually.

Comment: I am already using the libelf. And actually if I use nm I can see the "printf" symbol but not its address and the symbol is marked with the "U" letter for "Undefined". This is my problem, I use the address of the function to retrieve its name. But if the address is not stocked in the elf I can't retrieve the name. And yeah the libc is dynamically linked I guess

Comment: Are you reinventing `strace`?

Comment: I already recoded a strace for the school (I'm a student^^) and now we have to improve it to trace any kind of calls in a program

Comment: @ThibaudAuzou What does it say in the binary? It appears as though the linker renames `printf` to `__printf_chk` while linking but I'm not sure of this. Is dynamic linking involved?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand your question, I'm king of a beginner in this field. Do you want me to test something and to post the output ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may need to read up a little more about dynamic linking. Let's take `strlen` as an example symbol as `printf` is a bit special (fortification stuff).

Your problem is (I think) that you want to take the address of a symbol and translate that back into an address. You're trying to do this by parsing the ELF file of the program you are debugging. This works with symbols that are in your program, but not with dynamically linked symbols such as `strlen`. And you want to know how to resolve that.

The reason for that is that the address of symbols such as `strlen` are not held within your ELF program. They are instead unresolved references that are resolved dynamically *when the program loads*. Indeed modern Linux will (I believe) load dynamic libraries (which contain relocatable aka position independent code) in a randomised order and at randomised addresses, so the location of those symbols won't be known until the program loads.

For libraries that you have opened with `dlopen()` (i.e. where you are doing the loading yourself in the program), you can retrieve the address of such symbols using `dlsym()`; that's not much good if they are linked into the program at compile/link time.

On gcc, to resolve the position of symbols in general, use the gcc extension `dladdr()`. From the man page:

```
   The function dladdr() takes a function pointer and tries to
   resolve name and file where it is located.   Information  is
   stored in the Dl_info structure:

       typedef struct {
           const char *dli_fname;  /* Pathname of shared object that
                                      contains address */
           void       *dli_fbase;  /* Address at which shared object
                                      is loaded */
           const char *dli_sname;  /* Name of nearest symbol with address
                                      lower than addr */
           void       *dli_saddr;  /* Exact address of symbol named
                                      in dli_sname */
       } Dl_info;

   If no symbol matching addr could be found, then dli_sname and
   dli_saddr are set to NULL.

   dladdr() returns 0 on error, and nonzero on success.
```

I believe that will work for you.

For further information, I suggest you look at the [source](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/ltrace.git) to `ltrace` which traces library calls, and how [`backtrace_symbols`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols) (and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html)) works; note that particularly for non-global symbols this is going to be unreliable, and note the comment re adding `-r dynamic` to the link line.

You might also want to look at [addr2line](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html) and its [source](https://fossies.org/dox/binutils-2.25/addr2line_8c_source.html).